# How to convert AVG() function to decimal in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Help!
I have a table looks like the following one.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblshipline 
WHERE MethodShipped = 'FEDEX'
```

Then I get

```
Qtyshipped
2
3
15
3
10
9
10
```

Now the question is to calculate the AVERAGE of `qtyshipped` and round it to 2 decimal number.

My Code is

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(8,6), ROUND(AVG(Qtyshipped),2))  
FROM TblShipLine
WHERE MethodShipped= 'FEDEX'
```

The Answer should be `7.430000` ,
But it always returns `7.000000`. I appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we take your INT value and add 0.0 which is a fast conversion to float.  Then we apply the round() and convert()

```
Declare @YourTable table (Qtyshipped int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(2),
(3),
(15),
(3),
(10),
(9),
(10)

Select convert(decimal(8,6),round(Avg(Qtyshipped+0.0),2))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
7.430000
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm trying to get the form like `7.430000` . I use the following code and finally got it. `Select   ROUND(cast(Avg(Qtyshipped+0.00) as decimal(8,6)),2)
 From TblShipLine
 WHERE MethodShipped= 'FEDEX'`  thank you so much!

Comment: @Chao avg(int) will return an int...  so to circumvent that, we just add 0.0 to the value which is an implicit conversion to a float